What does just a closing bracket mean in an equation?
I'm reading a book on reinforement learning and came across several equations that have closing brackets without coresponding open brackets.  I came across one post which suggested that this can indicate creating a column vector, but I'm not sure that applies here.
The idea here is to show that the average value of a set of values is equal to the 1/N of  of the latest value sampled, plus the adjusted value of the sum of previously measured values.  I can't follow the math, though.  What does the ) mean?


I would check near the beginning and end of their book to see if they have a section defining the notation they use. Failing that, I'd look for the first place that you encounter this notation, and see if it's defined shortly before that.

It looks a bit like they just forgot the opening parentheses after $\frac{1}{N}$, but I don't understand how that can happen.

Btw, do you understand what the arrows mean?

Actually, yes, I think @Stefan is right; the notation of a single closing bracket is used to indicate that the author forgot some opening parentheses. Inserting an opening parenthesis after every $\frac1N$ in the formula should resolve the issue.

The arrows indicate iterative assignment.  So w1 = w0 + f(x).

This is the first occurrence in the book, and the preface doesn't mention this explicitly.  I've seen similar notation in other books on numerical analysis and AI, though, so I thought it might be some convention that I don't know about.

The book is Reinforcement Learning from O'Reilly Press, btw.

You might be right about the missing bracket, Stefan.  I guess I was overthinking this.

It’s not mathematical notation, it’s machine learning slang.

Even worse: eq. (6) looks wrong.

It seems to be 'missing bracket', but it is very strange to have same errors on 5 rows.

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/reinforcement-learning/9781492072386/

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/reinforcement-learning/9781492072386/ch01.html

It should read $$\begin{align}
r^{avg}N &\leftarrow \frac 1N\sum{i=1}^N r_i\
&\leftarrow \frac 1N\left(r_N+\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} r_i\right)\
&\leftarrow \frac 1N\left(r_N+(N-1)\frac1{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} r_i\right)\
&\leftarrow \frac 1N\left(r_N+(N-1)r^{avg}{N-1}\right)\
&\leftarrow \frac 1N\left(r_N+Nr^{avg}{N-1}-r^{avg}{N-1}\right)\
&\leftarrow r^{avg}{N-1} +\frac 1N\left(r_N-r^{avg}_{N-1}\right)\
\end{align}$$ as indicated by the fact that this calculation makes sense, while theirs doesn't without the inserted open parentheses.
